# function runs before other function although located later

Tags: angular, interpolation

I have in my angular based Html, 2 function executions.
The one that located before (located in interpolation) the other in terms of Html structure is executed last. The second function is based on something that the first one should do.
See my code, function **checkIfSetDataDidItsWork** isexecuting before **setData** :

```
{{ setData(data)}} //also display text in the Html
 <ng-container *ngIf="checkIfSetDataDidItsWork(data)">
 .....
</ng-container>
```

Is there a way to make sure that the first one in terms of Html flow executes before the second ?

Comment: Unable to understand! + [Unable to reproduce](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hulrtz-j3v9qt). Please feel free to provide stackblitz where we can reproduce it or with more details!

Comment: there is one way to make sure the first one has been called before second, maintain one flag by default it's value will b a false once `setData(data)` would executed than you can change that flag to true and put it in `*ngIf` with `checkIfSetDataDidItsWork(data)`, hope you are getting me let me know if you have an issue